# Choosing Correct papersize when printing with .NET PrintDocument

Tags: c#, printing, printdocument

When I am looping through each page I need to decide the size of a page and choose what size to print it in. is there an easy way to determine what size they are suppose to be?
right now i was going by the ratio of width and height. 
If ratio >= 1.64 && ratio <= 1.65 Then  Legal Size, 
If ratio >= 1.29 && ratio <= 1.30 The Letter Size.
but how about if they are printing other sizes do i have to do this for each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different things that can be considered the "size of a page": `PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings` is the default page settings from the printer driver. To determine "what size to print" I suggest using `PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Size` rather than the aspect ratio.

If you display a print controller this can be overridden on each page; use the PrintPage event's `PrintPageEventArgs.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Size`.